# NodeJS error when trying to redirect: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to redirect to another page in Express, however I keep receiving the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS message when it is attempted.

```
      app.get('/rand/:value', (request, response) => {
      response.redirect('test.html');
   });
```

':value' is the result of a randomly generated number which is sent to the server using fetch.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried including a leading `/` in your redirect, e.g. `response.redirect('/test.html');`?

Comment: @segFault when I do that the error message disappears, but nothing happens - there is no redirect.

Comment: I can see the test.html in Network when using inspect element but it doesn't actually redirect me.

Comment: try to use return statement. like return response.redirect('test.html');

Comment: Still no luck with this unfortunately